# Maven deploy to multiple remote hosts using ssh(scp)

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-deploy-plugin

I have a source library(apache storm) that uses maven, and after `mvn install ...` it compiles the library and installs jars to local maven repository. But now i have setup a cluster(multiple machines) that uses those jars to run their jobs and so after each compilation the new jars should be transmitted to all of those machines to use updated code. I would like to tell maven to compile project on my local machine and then transmit those jars(scp) to a specified location after each compilation to all of my cluster machines. because transferring them manually or via bash script is very error prone and cumbersome.

So is there a way to config maven to scp jar files of a specific project to multiple hosts? I should mention that maven is not installed on those hosts and i need just a simple scp command to send project artifacts to a specific directory in each machine (I've read couple of related questions but they don't apply to my problem, they use ftp or they want to send files to just one machine, etc)

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this link is helpfull: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html

Comment: @ FunThomas424242 thanks for the link, I saw that but there is no section for defining the path that jar file should be placed, and the part that explains settings.xml is'n clear enough! it says for unix platforms there is no need to define it, so how should i define the destination path of scp command in pom file.

Comment: I think the url of repository in the distributionManagement section is the machine + path to place the jar. For 1 machine i would define 1 repository for 2 machine 2 repository and so on. Works this? I could not try it currently - sorry. (for authenticate you will need for each repository id a related server id in the settings.xml) The source jar to transfer should be the main artifact of your build - you can attach artifacts if needed.